# Delete Node by Searching for reference java

Tags: java, reference, linked-list

So I wrote a linkList that holds a student reference and a next reference. I have no issue with insertion. On the other hand, I need help with deletion and finding the item. So basically I'm using the find method to find a student reference to a string. Then using a delete method to delete the node corresponding with that reference.

```
   public void deleteStudentNode(StudentNode delete)
   { 
          StudentNode it = new StudentNode();
          delete = shead;
          it = shead; 
          //StudentNode b = new StudentNode();

          while(it.getSptr() != findStudentByName(""))        
          {
             delete = it;
             it = it.getSptr();
          }
          delete.setSptr(null);         
          setShead(delete);
          //d.setStudent(null);                
   }

   public StudentNode findStudentByName (String findName)
   {
            StudentNode find = shead;

      while(find.getStudent().getName() != findName)
      {
         if(find.getSptr() == null)

            return null;

         else

            find = find.getSptr();      
      }
                  return find; 
   }
```

Comment: I don't know if it is the only problem, but you should use `equals` to compare strings instead of `==`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839).

Comment: @RobinKrahl sorry, didn't read your comment properly. Yes, for comparing strings you should use `equals`

Comment: @esin88 . I Notice that but I'm not understanding the approach. its confusing me

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend implementing `Iterable` interface for your one-linked list. After that all you need to do is

```
public void deleteByName(StudentList studentList, String nameToDelete) {
    Iterator iterator = studentList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        if(iterator.next().getName().equals(nameToDelete)) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Hint, for iterating through one-linked list you need 2 pointers: for current element and for previous.

Comment: thank you for your answer, ive like it so far. The only issue is I cant use this interface. have to strictly use the methods I have. but I understand the iterator you have.

Comment: @Qwanny you mean you have to use exactly these 2 methods? `deleteStudentNode(StudentNode delete)` and `findStudentByName (String findName)`?

Comment: no problem now ive actually gotten it to work. now I'm trying to for a link list inside of another one